# Bind Service 'getter' or $watch changes and update manually - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service

In my AngularJS app I'm using a service to store info that's being updated by a simple polling mechanism. Then, my controllers/directives are reading from that service, so that I can have that model data in a single place, avoiding some possibly repeated information across other scopes.

While developing this solution I've wondered if this is the best way to do this.

Currently each controller's scope only has the keys of the objects they're tracking. I then bind the 'getter' method of the service to the scope so that they keep the binding -- when the service gets an update, the object collection is replaced so I can't bind the object itself or else I'll loose the binding. The same happens with directives, I'm injecting the service as a dependency and using the retrieved data to display some info:

```
// SERVICE
app.factory('updateService', function($interval) {
    var data = {
        '1': {
            'id': 1,
            'info': true,
             ...
        },
        '2': {
            'id',2,
            'info': false,
            ...
        }
    };

    return {
        getDataObj: function(id) {
            return data[id];
        },
        isObjectInfoTrue: function(id) {
            return data[id] && data[id]['info'] === true;
        },
        getObjStatus: function(id) {
            return data[id] && foo();
        }
});

// CONTROLLER
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'updateService', function ($scope, updateService) {
    $scope.getDataObj = updateService.getDataObj;   

    // Id's to follow
    $scope.keys = [1,3];

  }]);

// DIRECTIVE
app.directive('renderData', ['updateService', function(updateService) {
return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
        obj: '=obj'
    },
    link : function(scope,element,attrs) {
        scope.getDataObj = updateService.getDataObj;
        scope.isObjectInfoTrue = updateService.isObjectInfoTrue;
        scope.getObjStatus = updateService.getObjStatus;

    },
    template: '<div ng-if="obj && isObjectInfoTrue(obj.id)" ng-class="getObjStatus(obj.id)" class="obj" style="border:1px solid red">{{}}</div>'
  };
}]);


// HTML
<li ng-repeat="key in keys">        
    <render-data obj="getDataObj(key)"/>
</li>
```

I like this option but I'm afraid of the number of repeated function calls consulting the service's object and its behaviour when the size of the service object increases a lot. Is it scalable when compared to the other option? Which I guess would be having each scope separately on the controllers, using $watch to listen for changes on the service data and then updating each controller scope individually.

Thanks in advance